# how to recover a .c file in AIX unix which has removed (rm -f) by accidentally

Tags: unix, ibm, aix

how to recover a .c file in AIX unix which has removed (rm -f) by accidentally

Answer (score 3):

Just grab it from your daily/weekly backups

You have backups right?

Coincidentally, there is an [FAQ at FAQS](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/aix-faq/part1/section-54.html) for this. Follow directions at your own peril...

Comment: Deleted file has not checked in CVS server yet. It's newly created file.

Answer (score 3):

If your FS is not journal-enabled and you remember any "unique" string in the content of the file you can use as a search seed a simple way is to:

- mount the partition ***ro*** (or unmount it, if it is possible) in order to *avoid 
  accidental overwrite of the sectors involved*
- **grep the partition device for the string you really know the deleted file has to contain**

Of course you have to adjust -B and -A grep options, in order to be able to retrieve the entire file (set the lines before and after the searching string you have to grep). Redirect grep output on a new file and adjust it to remove exceeding heading and trailing lines.

I used this method a number of times, with very good results.

```
grep -i -B 1000 -A 1000 \
      "your seed string you are really sure to find in the deleted file" \
      /dev/your-device-partition
```